# MAUI Set FlyoutFooterTemplate Label value to App version

Tags: c#, binding, maui, flyout

I have a Label in a FlyoutFooterTemplate DataTemplate in my Shell App and I would like to set it to the current App Version (AppInfo.Current.VersionString) but I am having a hard time trying to accomplish this simple task.
I have no clue on how to access the lblVersion label inside the template programmatically and I can't find a way to bind the Text property of the label to a static string I defined in my AppShell.xaml.cs class:

```
        public static string AppVersion { get; } = AppInfo.Current.VersionString;
```

and this is part of the code inside my AppShell.xaml file

```
  <Shell.FlyoutFooterTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
      <Grid ColumnDefinitions="0.8*,0.2*" Padding="10">
          <Label x:Name="lblVersion"  TextColor="Red" 
            FontAutoScalingEnabled="True"
            FontSize="Body"
            VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            Margin="10"></Label>
      </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
  </Shell.FlyoutFooterTemplate>
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing seems pretty close. Just set up your binding for the `Label.Text`:

```
<Label
    x:Name="lblVersion"
    Text="{Binding AppVersion}"
    TextColor="Red"             
    FontAutoScalingEnabled="True"
    FontSize="Body"
    VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" 
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    Margin="10"/>
```

Then make sure the binding context is set.

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        BindingContext = this;  
        InitializeComponent(); 
    }
    public string AppVersion { get; } = $"Version {AppInfo.Current.VersionString}";
}
```

Should work:

[image: screenshot]

---

**Alternative**

You may want to experiment with instantiating a `FlyoutFooter` on the spot, instead of a template.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="version_in_flyout_footer.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:version_in_flyout_footer"
    Shell.FlyoutBackgroundColor="Azure"
    Shell.FlyoutWidth="200"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout">
    <ShellContent
        Title="Home"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" >
    </ShellContent>
    <FlyoutItem Title="News">
        <ShellContent  />
    </FlyoutItem>
    <FlyoutItem Title="About">
        <ShellContent  />
    </FlyoutItem>
    <Shell.FlyoutFooter>
        <Grid 
            ColumnDefinitions="0.8*,0.2*"
            Padding="10">
            <Label
                x:Name="lblVersion"
                TextColor="Red"             
                FontAutoScalingEnabled="True"
                FontSize="Body"
                VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Margin="10"/>
        </Grid>
    </Shell.FlyoutFooter>
</Shell>
```

... and just set the value.

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lblVersion.Text = $"Version {AppInfo.Current.VersionString}";
    }
}
```

---

*The difference: Using a template means that the corresponding `View` will instantiate in a "Lazy" way and so will be deferred to the first time the Flyout is shown (if ever). This can make startup faster, for example, when you have several complex page views. In the second version, the `FlyoutFooter` instantiates while the app is initializing, increasing the time it takes to show the main view, but in a miniscule way in this case.*

---